# Estimating network I/O speed using scp

Tags: linux, bandwidth, scp

I want to have a rough estimate of the network I/O speed between two linux servers. The problem is that I don't have sudo access to the servers. So I tried transferring a 1GB file between the two servers using scp. I suppose that with the encryption there will be some slowdown. How much slowdown should I be expecting? Also can the scp bandwidth usage be capped by the server admin? How do I know if it is capped?

Comment: Try asking here: http://serverfault.com

Comment: See my answer for a bash script to measure performance and also some explanation of the types of throttling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The encryption is normally not the bottleneck in a scp transfer, but you can use ftp instead.

My usual way is to open a Python web server on any directory on a certain port using this single command

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000  # python 2
python -m http.server 8000 # python 3
```

And on the other side just use wget to download it

```
wget http://[ip address]:8000/[some big file]
```

Any network activity could be limited by the server admin and the usual indicator is that your speed is maintained at a nice stable level (e.g. 500KB/s)

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! Worked like a charm =)

Comment: For those reading this in the python3 world of 2022, SimpleHTTPServer is now http.server, but this answer is still as good as it was 10+ years ago. Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

`iperf` is there for network performance testing, available in all good repositories, and plenty of articles for usage tips.

http://iperf.sourceforge.net/

Random usage articles:

http://www.nanog.org/meetings/nanog43/presentations/Dugan_Iperf_N43.pdf

http://maddhat.com/testing-network-performance-using-iperf-3

Using file transfer programs like `scp` or `ftp` brings in disk IO as a bottleneck source.

Comment: but installing iperf requires sudo permission which as I mentioned I don't have. But thanks for bringing up the disk IO bottleneck. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: That's not how Linux/Unix works, you can download the source and build it on the server, or just copy the binary from another machine.  No superuser rights are required to build or run `iperf`.

Answer (score 1):

**How much slowdown should I be expecting?** Encryption should not be much overhead. Also, the purpose of this speed test is to measure sever to server I/O performance, so wouldn't you want that to reflect the typical type of communication, which would be with encryption?

**Also can the scp bandwidth usage be capped by the server admin? How do I know if it is capped?** Yes, this is possible at various tiers in the network. For example, using `tc` (example [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-limit-bandwidth-on-linux-to-better-test-your-applications/)), and at the router level. If you have `sudo` privileges you can check if `tc` limits are in place. Otherwise, you could try using a different machine without limits and see if the speed is different. If it's done at the router level you have no easy way of knowing.

**Here's a bash script** that will 1) check if a server is reachable, 2) create a file of a given size, 3) use `scp` to measure upload and optionally download rates, 4) delete the file locally and remotely.

Use it like `speed_test.sh --server=1.2.3.4 --test_size=128 --do_download=1 --server_dir=.`

Credit note: It is my modification of the script originally posted [here](https://gist.github.com/patmandenver/fe5648c6faad8f49ef8dd705a509bb7f).

```sh
#!/bin/bash

test_file=".scp-test-file"

# usage function
function usage()
{
   cat << HEREDOC
   Usage: $progname --server=<ip address> [--test_size=<MB> --do_download=<0/1> --server_dir=<server side dir>]
   optional arguments:
     -h, --help           show this help message and exit
HEREDOC
}

# initialize variables and defaults
progname=$(basename $0)
server=
server_dir=./
do_download=1
test_size=10

###
# all args
L=(server \
do_download \
test_size \
server_dir)

arg_parse_str="help"
for arg in "${L[@]}"; do
    arg_parse_str=${arg_parse_str},${arg}:
done
#echo $arg_parse_str

OPTS=$(getopt -o "h" --long ${arg_parse_str} -n "$progname" -- "$@")
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Error in command line arguments." >&2 ; usage; exit 1 ; fi
eval set -- "$OPTS"

while true; do
  # uncomment the next line to see how shift is working
  # echo "\$1:\"$1\" \$2:\"$2\""
  case "$1" in
    -h | --help ) usage; exit; ;;
    -- ) shift; break ;;
  esac
  found=
  for arg in "${L[@]}"; do
    if [ "$1" == "--$arg" ]; then
        declare ${arg}="$2";
        shift 2;
        found=1
        break
    fi
  done
  if [ -z "$found" ]; then
    break
  fi
done

if [ -z "$server" ]
then
    usage;
    exit;
fi

#[[ -z $(nc -W 1 -w 10 $server 22 2>/dev/null) ]] && echo "$server unreachable" && exit 0
#if your nc complains about not having -i command line option then use the line above
[[ -z $(nc -i 1 -w 10 $server 22 2>/dev/null) ]] && echo "$server unreachable" && exit 0


# generate a file of all zeros
echo "Generating $test_size MB test file..."
dd if=/dev/zero of=$test_file bs=$(echo "$test_size*1024*1024" | bc) \
  count=1 &> /dev/null
# upload test

echo "Testing upload to $server..."
up_speed=$(scp -v -o 'Compression no' -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' $test_file $server:$server_dir/$test_file 2>&1 | \
  grep "Bytes per second" | \
  sed "s/^[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\).*$/\1/g")
up_speed=$(echo "($up_speed/1000)" | bc)
echo "Upload speed:   $up_speed KBps on $server"

if [ "$do_download" == "1" ]; then
    # download test
    echo "Testing download from $server..."
    down_speed=$(scp -v -o 'Compression no' -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' $server:$server_dir/$test_file $test_file 2>&1 | \
      grep "Bytes per second" | \
      sed "s/^[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\).*$/\2/g")
    down_speed=$(echo "($down_speed/1000)" | bc)
    echo "Download speed: $down_speed KBps on $server"
fi

# clean up
echo "Removing test file, $server:$server_dir/$test_file..."
ssh $server "rm $server_dir/$test_file"
echo "Removing test file locally..."
rm $test_file
```